# What are some pagerank alternatives?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

This is strictly related to the graph algorithm(not SEO or anything).  I'm interested in knowing if there are other  algorithms out there that solely use the structure of a graph(not content like keywords, etc) to make inferences?

So for example, if your given a large graph full of nodes how can you make inferences assuming  you have no idea what the values within the nodes actually mean(for example, pagerank knows who's linking(edges) to whom and doesn't know anything about the content itself)?

This is not exclusive to web searching, anything that uses graph structure to make inferences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As well as HITS [as suggested by @larsmans], there is also [SALSA](http://www.cparity.com/projects/AcmClassification/samples/383041.pdf), which is concidered more "stable" from HITS [and thus is less vulnerable to be affected by spammers].

You are also encourage to have a look at this [survey or ranking algorithms](http://www.divms.uiowa.edu/~asignori/phd/report/a-survey-of-ranking-algorithms.pdf)

Comment: Twitter use SALSA in their user recommendation technique.

Answer (score 2):

The main alternative to PageRank is [HITS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HITS_algorithm).

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative to page rank is [OPIC](http://www2003.org/cdrom/papers/refereed/p007/p7-abiteboul.html).